# xsltproc failing when trying to implement paypal iframe

Tags: xml, paypal, escaping

hello I am using xsltproc to combine XML and XSL to create HTML Files.

so far so good until now.

I need to add:

```
<iframe src='https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=776OIGIHemE6xgpGcckDzIA8o&SECURETOKENID=c85d4c2610a92d761b7f445eaa55a7ff&MODE=TEST' width='490' height='565' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'>
```

but the xslt proc fails due to some of the characters in the 'src' I think the  =   is giving me problems

how do I escape these?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the ampersand &. You will need to make sure it is escaped as & in your XSLT. If you are using attribute value templates, it should look something like this:

```
<iframe 
   src='https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN={$token}&amp;SECURETOKENID={$tokenid}&amp;MODE=TEST' 
   width='490' height='565' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'>
```

Comment: how do I fill in the toke value? I tried:
    <xsl:attribute name="token">tokenvaluehere</xsl:attribute>    but this does something else.

Comment: In my example, **$token** would be a variable. If you could edit your question, to show the XSLT you are currently using to generate the IFrame element, then I could be a bit more precise. Thanks!